# Spark: How to collect a single column from an ArrayType of columns to a different array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column called `requests` which is of ArrayType and a few fields within it like `code`, `value` etc

```
StructField(requests,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(code,IntegerType,true), StructField(value,DoubleType,true) .....)
```

So something like `[[1, 5.0....], [2, 0, ....]]` etc.

How do I collect just the `code` fields in an array so I get just `[1,2....]`? I'm not interested in other fields within `requests`.

I tried using `array_zip` but that didn't help:

```
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", arrays_zip(col("requests.code")))
```

Do I have to use `explode`? Or is this possible using Higher-Order Functions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a higher-order function `transform` for Spark >= 2.4:

```
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", expr("transform(requests, x -> x.code)"))
```

If you have Spark >= 3.0, you can also use the Scala dataframe API `transform`:

```
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", transform(col("requests"), x => x("code")))

// or more simply
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", transform(col("requests"), _("code")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an array of `code` values directly by accessing the field in the `requests` array:

```scala
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", col("requests")("code"))
```

Or by using column methods `getItem`, `getField`:

```scala
val result = df.withColumn("new_col", col("requests").getField("code"))
```

Example:

```scala
result.show(false)
//+----------------------------------------+------------+
//|requests                                |new_col     |
//+----------------------------------------+------------+
//|[[1, 1.5], [2, 2.5], [3, 3.5], [4, 4.5]]|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
//+----------------------------------------+------------+
```